# How do you make this pseudocode merge function algorithm for my mergeSort recursive?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, merge

```
merge(A[p..r],q)

k<-0
i<-p
j<-q+1

while(i<=q && j<=r){
    if A[i]<= A[j]
        B[++k]<-A[i++]
    else
        B[++k]<-A[j++]
}

for m <-i to q
    B[++k]<-A[m]
for n <- j to r
B[++k]<-A[n]

i<-p
for e <- i to k
    A[i++]<-B[e]
```

> I know that recursive functions must call itself to perform the algorithm.
>   but I can't wrap my brain about its concept can you help me start writing it recursively?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a functioning `merge()` function, you need to think

> How can I split the problem to smaller problems, and then use my
>   `merge()` function to combine the answer

This idea is to split the array to 2 halves, recursively invoke `mergeSort()` on each half. The assumption is the recursive algorithm works correctly, so when you return from the recursion - each half is now sorted.

So, you basically have 2 sorted arrays, which you need to merge into a single one, using your `merge()` function.

The pseudo code should look something like:

```
mergeSort(arr, start, end):
   if (end-start) <= 1: //array of size 1 is already sorted
        return
   mid = (end-start)/2 + start
   mergeSort(arr,start,mid)
   mergeSort(arr,mid+1,end)
   //here, you assume that mergeSort works, 
   //thus each half of the array is sorted on its own
   merge(arr,start,end,mid)
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you!! But i have a question, can I still use loops in a recursive function or it will become iterative?

Comment: @Watchmen07 You can, of course. A recursive algorithm is called so because its usage of recursion - not lack of loops.